# c# 5 webbrowser with 5 diffrent cookies?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have five different web browser components that I have made, and I'm trying to figure out how to have a specific cookie for each one.

Answer (score 1):

The WebbroserControl uses the InternetExplorer to navigate to Websites.

Either use HttpWebrequest to navigate to the site, handle cookies and display it in the WebbrowserControl or use InternetSetCookieEx and InternetGetCookieEx WinApi calls to read and write cookies direkt to the Internetexplorer.

Comment: but i have 5 diffrent webbrowsers how do i make a custom cookie for all of them?

Comment: Can´t help you if you don´t show any code. Therefore was my statement as precise as it can be with the information you provided.